# When to use a cell, matrix, or table in Matlab

Tags: matlab, data-structures, matrix, dataset, cell-array

I am fairly new to matlab and I am trying to figure out when it is best to use cells, tables, or matrixes to store sets of data and then work with the data.

What I want is to store data that has multiple lines that include strings and numbers and then want to work with the numbers.

For example a line would look like

```
'string 1' , time, number1, number 2
```

. I know a matrix works best if al elements are numbers, but when I use a cell I keep having to convert the numbers or strings to a matrix in order to work with them. I am running matlab 2012 so maybe that is a part of the problem. Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: FYI, [`table`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/table.html) (and its predecessor [`dataset`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/dataset-class.html) from the Statistics toolbox) is a class implemented underneath using cell-arrays, along with easier indexing, convenient functions, and nicer output display. You can read the code if you want `which table`

Comment: Do they explicitly need to be stored in the same variable? could you work with a matrix for each of the 4 columns?

You could also try creating a matrix for each of the 4 columns and grouping them with cells

Comment: If I did that would I still have to use cell2mat to access the matrixes in each of the cells?

Comment: @AustenNovis you don't need to use cell2mat to address a matrix in a cell. `test{1} = [1 2; 3 4];` `test{1}(2,2)` returns `4`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a matrix when :

- the tabular data has a uniform type (all are floating points like `double`, or integers like `int32`);
- & either the amount of data is small, or is big and has static (predefined) size;
- & you care about the speed of accessing data, or you need matrix operations performed on data, or some function requires the data organized as such.

Use a cell array when:

- the tabular data has heterogeneous type (mixed element types, "jagged" arrays etc.);
- | there's a lot of data and has dynamic size;
- | you need only indexing the data numerically (no algebraic operations);
- | a function requires the data as such.

Same argument for structs, only the indexing is by name, not by number.

Not sure about tables, <s>I don't think is offered by the language itself; might be an UDT that I don't know of...</s>

**Later edit**

These three types may be combined, in the sense that cell arrays and structs may have matrices *and* cell arrays and structs as elements (because thy're heterogeneous containers). In your case, you might have 2 approaches, depending on how you need to access the data:

- if you access the data mostly by row, then an array of N structs (one struct per row) with 4 fields (one field per column) would be the most effective in terms of performance;
- if you access the data mostly by column, then a single struct with 4 fields (one field per column) would do; first field would be a cell array of strings for the first column, second field would be a cell array of strings or a 1D matrix of doubles depending on how you want to store you dates, the rest of the fields are 1D matrices of `double`s.

Answer (score 1):

Concerning tables: I always used matrices or cell arrays until I
had to do database related things such as joining datasets by a unique key; the only way I found to do this in was by using tables. It takes a while to get used to them and it's a bit annoying that some functions that work on cell arrays don't work on tables vice versa. MATLAB could have done a better job explaining when to use one or the other because it's not super clear from the documentation.

Answer (score 0):

The situation that you describe, seems to be as follows:

You have several columns. Entire columns consist of 1 datatype each, and all columns have an equal number of rows.

This seems to match exactly with the recommended situation for using a `[table][1]`

> T = table(var1,...,varN) creates a table from the input variables,
>   var1,...,varN . Variables can be of different sizes and data types,
>   but all variables must have the same number of rows.

Actually I don't have much experience with tables, but if you can't figure it out you can always switch to using 1 cell array for the first column, and a matrix for all others (in your example).

Comment: I think tables were introduced in R2013B. I guess cells or structs are the best approaches.

Comment: or `dataset` from the Statistics toolbox

Comment: As @Amro mentioned, the dataset can be used as well (sometimes you will even have to). But [it is recommended to use tables if you can](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/103851-what-are-the-differences-between-dataset-and-table-in-matlab-8-2-r2013b).